# Problems in Website after uploading to server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having few issues after uploading my website to godaddy server. My website link is [http://www.sujanshrestha.info.np/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WaWkS.png)

In my console tab there are three errors. Please look into the attachment.
[image]
Due to these errors icons are not showing in the services section.

And another main issue is the main front cover pic at the top of the website, it is showing well in desktop version but the picture is not showing in the mobile version.
Please look into the attachment.
[image]

Here is the code for the cover pic:

```
<div class="coverPic">
  <div class="frontText">
    <span class="frontText-1">
      <span  class="frontText-2">Hey, I'm</span>
      <h3><strong>Sujan Shrestha</strong></h3>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.coverPic{
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0.7;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;

/*
    fixed: Parallax
    scroll: normal
*/

  background-attachment: fixed;
}

 .coverPic{
     background-image: url('../images/coverPic.jpeg');
     min-height: 100%;
 }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Firstly check links to your fonts. It seems like your server either cannot return these files or links are wrong. I guess you need to check server logs since error 500 is an internal server error and therefore should be shown in logs

Comment: since it is wordpress, i think you might have to upload those assets using the wordpress, though i have no idea how wordpress works,

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these lines to `.coverPic`. The image does work on my phone in Google Chrome.

```
-o-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
```

As for the internal error: It seems to happen on every route.

> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I therefore believe something is wrong in your `.htaccess` file. Could you provide this for further detail?

Comment: Its not working in the iphone safari/chrome browser.

Comment: @SujanShrestha And if you use `-webkit-` in front of every `background` property?

Comment: It seems the cover pic is not working in IPHONES only. In android it is working perfectly.